# What is best to distinguish between file and dir path in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have the list of strings from the Amazon S3 API service which contain the full file path, like this:

```
fileA.jpg
fileB.jpg
images/
```

I want to put partition folders and files into different lists.

How can I divide them?

I was thinking of regex like this:

```
for path in list:
    if re.search("/$",path)
        dir_list.append(path)
    else
        file_list.append(path)
```

is there any better way?

Comment: OP, are these filenames on the local computer? If so, you can use `os.path.isdir` to tell whether they're directories. If not, you have to use some approximation (e.g. `endswith("/")`).

Comment: @katrielalex  No they are on amazon s3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression; just use `.endswith('/')`:

```
for path in lst:
    if path.endswith('/'):
        dir_list.append(path)
    else:
        file_list.append(path)
```

`.endswith()` performs better than a regular expression and is simpler to boot:

```
>>> sample = ['fileA.jpg', 'fileB.jpg', 'images/'] * 30
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(sample)
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import re
>>> def re_partition(pattern=re.compile(r'/$')):
...     for e in sample:
...         if pattern.search(e): pass
...         else: pass
... 
>>> def endswith_partition():
...     for e in sample:
...         if e.endswith('/'): pass
...         else: pass
... 
>>> timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import re_partition as f, sample', number=10000)
0.2553541660308838
>>> timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import endswith_partition as f, sample', number=10000)
0.20675897598266602
```

Comment: @katrielalex: At which point you are up a creek without a paddle and no means to distinguish reliably between files and directories *anyway*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Up a creek where os.path.isdir doesn't exist? Not my downvote btw.

Comment: @Junuxx: I've edited the title of the question, which was indeed misleading. The *body* of the question on the other hand shows this is *not* about local filenames.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:"An API service" doesn't necessarily mean it isn't local imo. But maybe I made up my mind before I reached the end of the question :p

Comment: @Junuxx: The OP will have to clarify that further then; I've moved the 'service API' part to the top so people get to read that first. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters files are on amazon s3

Answer (score 2):

From [Filter a list into two parts](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201306/filter_a_list_into_two_parts.html), an iterable version:

```
from itertools import tee

a, b = tee((p.endswith("/"), p) for p in paths)
dirs = (path for isdir, path in a if isdir)
files = (path for isdir, path in b if not isdir)
```

It allows to consume an infinite stream of paths from the service if both `dirs` and `files` generators are advanced nearly in sync.

Comment: If not advanced nearly in sync one of the `tee` object will act as a cache.

Comment: @user1958218: `isdir` is the result of `p.endswith("/")`

Comment: but where r u assigning that value to isdir. is that system variable avaiable in python or we need to assign value to it. i can't see where u r assigning value to it

Comment: @user1958218: it is called "sequence unpacking". Here, it is used with a for-loop  e.g., `for x, y in [(1,2), (3,4)]: print(x)` – each tuple is unpacked into (x,y) i.e., it prints `1` and `3`.

Comment: @Sebas How can i remove slash before putting name in dir

Comment: @user1958218: to remove zero or more `'/'` from the end of a string: `s = s.rstrip('/')`. If it is unclear; [ask new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools` module for item grouping:

```
import itertools

items = ["fileA.jpg","fileB.jpg","images/"]
sorter = lambda x:x.endswith("/")
items = sorted(items, key=sorter) #in case items are not sorted
files, dirs = [tuple(i[1]) for i in itertools.groupby(items, sorter)]

print(files, dirs)
```

Comment: This requires the input to be sorted. As it happens, the *sample* is sorted, but how do you know the real results are still sorted with directories listed last?